# Hibernate: Bulk insert gives commit error in the end

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing a pretty simple bulk insert into a Mysql database from a json file like so.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ImportFileParserImpl{
    public boolean importFile(String filePath, Session session) 
          throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
    session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath), "UTF-8");
    logger.info("Start Reading Entry...");

    int count = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject JsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(scanner.nextLine());
        DPSJsonConverter singleJSONEntry = new DPSJsonConverter();
        singleJSONEntry = new Gson().fromJson(JsonObj.toString(), 
                   DPSJsonConverter.class);

        DpsModel singleDBEntry = singleJSONEntry.getDPSModel();

        logger.info("Saving: " + singleDBEntry.toString());

        session.save(singleDBEntry);
        if (count % 100 == 0) {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.clear();
            session.beginTransaction();

            logger.info("Save committed. Current index: " + count);
        }
        count++;
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    scanner.close();
    session.clear();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
    logger.info("Finished Reading");

    return true;
}
  }
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:559)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.saveData(Unknown Source)
    at de.it2media.Start.main(Start.java:29)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:172)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    ... 9 more
```

The import does complete and the database table gets populated fully as intended so no problems there. I'm guessing that I get this error because of the `session.beginTransaction();` call inside the `if` block. But without it I can't import the whole thing.

I have also debugged the code but I get the error way after the method is finished.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

for batch insert you should follow the below steps

1. set the flush to manual mode
2. begin the transaction
3. create loop
4. inside loop flush and clear
5. commit the transacation

you are doing opposite  way

Comment: I want to commit the transaction after every 100 inserts so that the data so far processed appears in the database table before the whole thing is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You are using commit on transaction before calling the begin.

change the code as below:

Check the below code for more information:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ImportFileParserImpl {
    public boolean importFile(String filePath, Session session)
            throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
        session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath), "UTF-8");
        logger.info("Start Reading Entry...");

        int count = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if(count==0){
                session.beginTransaction();
            }
            JSONObject JsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser()
                    .parse(scanner.nextLine());
            DPSJsonConverter singleJSONEntry = new DPSJsonConverter();
            singleJSONEntry = new Gson().fromJson(JsonObj.toString(),
                    DPSJsonConverter.class);

            DpsModel singleDBEntry = singleJSONEntry.getDPSModel();

            logger.info("Saving: " + singleDBEntry.toString());

            session.save(singleDBEntry);
            if(count==99)
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            if (count % 100 == 0 && count != 0) {
                session.clear();
                session.beginTransaction();

                logger.info("Save committed. Current index: " + count);
            }
            count++;
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        scanner.close();
        session.clear();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        logger.info("Finished Reading");

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that before. And I get the error `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported`